# Ubuntu not starting, have to start using old kernel

Tags: kernel, 18.04, startup

My Ubuntu 18.04 is not starting. On going to advanced option I can see kernel 4.15.0.33 and 4.15.0.30. Each time I have to manually select kernel 4.15.0.30 to start Ubuntu.

Help.

Comment: Use the old kernel , remove the new one, and file a bug report, but we need more details

Comment: I am not a pro, please help me with the commands

Comment: This is in the purple screen at startup right? GRUB?  "Not starting" is very vague. Please provide more details.

Comment: I asked the question 7 days back, already installed a fresh OS, don't remember in details. The last point was a after some white writings, a dark screen with no progress there after for the first time. Next time onwards a screen with 5 options, one being boot using old kernel.

Comment: It was working absolutely fine with when I booted with old kernel. But after following commands given in the answer by some crazy user, my system totally crashed and didn't boot at all with a black screen in which white letters started flowing hours after hours automatically. Then I made a fresh OS install.